# How to build github project with no build file?

Tags: java, github, repository, release, building

basically i am looking to edit the program to fit my own specific use case
but i have literally 0 clue on how to build it, it has no sl file so i am need someone to point it out.

https://github.com/Ajarmar/universal-pokemon-randomizer-zx/releases

Well i tried to build with visual studio, or going into gradle and messing around but i cant figure it out i am clueless on this. so any help would be welcome ngl. also i need it to be a .jar file

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is neither a build script nor a hint in the documentation.

The github repository states that the whole thing is a java project - but no hints for gradle, maven, ant or even some shell script.

All in all it may be best to ask the developer Ajarmar. If he does not respond all you can do is poke in the dark.